# Dynamically setting Styles for View : Android

Tags: android-layout, android, android-styles

> I want to change the look (Style) of various views *dynamically* in an
>   Activity. But on going through various blogs, ***I came to know that
>   android does not support dynamically setting styles for Views
>   programmatic / dynamic.***, though I am not sure.

1) Is there any other ways of implementing apart from making use *THEMES* or making use layout *xml files having styles pre set* ?

2) Is it possible to set the different styles for various views (say *green colour text for* **TextView1** and *red color text for* **TextView2**) by making use of setTheme() for entire Activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text color in your java file like this.

```
textview1.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

textview2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. setting color is just for example. It will contain much more details than that such as rounded corner,divier thickness,text font ,etc...

Answer (score 1):

Use this xml file in as resource and add it in drawable folder.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <gradient
    android:angle="90"
    android:centerColor="#f77b2d"
    android:endColor="#f99f66"
    android:startColor="#f66a11" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0.5dp"
        android:color="#313437" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp" />

 </shape>
```